# How to convert custom type definition file to npm type definition file

Tags: typescript, coffeescript, typescript-typings, module-augmentation

I have a custom module definition file for a dependency written in CoffeeScript in my typescript project.

It looks like the following and works great:

**src/@types/dependency-name.d.ts**

```js
declare module 'dependency-name' {
  import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3';

  /**
  * omitted
  */

  interface ICable {
    new (channels: Record<string, ISubscription>): ICable;

    channels: Record<string, ISubscription>;

    channel: (name: string) => ISubscription | undefined;
    setChannel: (name: string, channel: ISubscription) => ISubscription;
  }
  export const Cable: ICable;
}
```

So I want to contribute to this project and submit a type definition file.

What I tried is:

1. Forked the original CoffeeScript project,
2. Copied the above definition to `index.d.ts`
3. Add the following line to `pacakge.json`:

```
"typings": "index.d.ts",
```

4. Installed forked repository in my typescript project for testing.

However, it does not recognize the added `index.d.ts` file. Shows type definition is missing error.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215276/11792577) and guessed that the issue is this one:

> be written as external modules

But I don't understand it. Can someone guide me to convert my custom typing (module augmentation, I guess?) to correct type definition file for `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking directly at the [TypeScript handbook page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) linked from the post you linked, as the post itself is rather old and the copy of the text there is a bit outdated. In particular, `"types"` is now preferred over `"typings"` in `package.json`, although both should still work.

However, you and the post are correct that the issue is one of ambient external modules ("ambient modules") vs. non-ambient ones ("external modules"). You should just need to remove the `declare module` block wrapping around your file, leaving its contents at the top level. That will transform your declarations from ambient to non-ambient and should make it work.