# Typescript using d.ts files from node_modules

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, node-modules, vite

I created a node module with vite and used it on my project.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
root
|-my-module
||-lib
|||-index.d.ts // contains all definitions for components
|||-dict.enum.d.ts // contains a dictionary
||-src
|||-components
||||-MyComponent.vue
|||-dict.enum.ts
|||-main.ts
|||-App.vue
|-project
```

Now I am installing this module using `npm install ../my-module` which works fine besides typescript does not find the definition files. I need to add my own `types.d.ts` to my `project` folder in order to have no compiler errors.

How can I use the generated definition files?

this is what my tsconfig looks like:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    /* Typing */
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/my-module"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

### EDIT 1

This is my package.json

```json
{
    [...]
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vite",
        "build": "vue-tsc --declaration && vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "main": "./lib/my-module.umd.cjs",
    "module": "./lib/my-module.js",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./lib/my-module.js",
            "require": "./lib/my-module.umd.cjs"
        },
        "./style.css": "./lib/style.css"
    },
    "types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
    "dependencies": {
        "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.5.2",
        "vue": "^3.3.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6",
        "vite": "^4.4.5",
        "vite-plugin-svg-icons": "^2.0.1",
        "vue-tsc": "^1.8.8"
    }
}
```

By now I realized that the problem more occurred because of what the vite-plugin-dts creates. This is my Vite config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import path, { resolve } from "path";
import { createSvgIconsPlugin } from "vite-plugin-svg-icons";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        dts({
            rollupTypes: true 
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        outDir: './lib',
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/main.ts"),
            name: "MyModule",
            fileName: "my-module",
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ["vue"],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    vue: "Vue",
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

When I run the build script I get an index.d.ts with the content `export * from '/main.ts'` but I don't know why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a typescript definition file to a npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210059/how-to-add-a-typescript-definition-file-to-a-npm-package)

Comment: Can you give us the package.json of your lib, it's where you should reference your d.ts

Comment: @yoduh unfortunately not. I think my rollup is the problem

Comment: @Samuel I did update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if at some point someone finds this thread and needs some guidance here is how I solved my problems:

First:
Remove any declarations from the project you want to import your library into. You won't need them. I tried pointing towards my node module inside my tsconfig, which did not work.

Second:
Create a index.ts inside of `./module/src` which you will use to export your components. I used my `main.ts` which could also work but I would not be able to test my modules properly without having an actual app.
In your `index.ts` you will import/export your components. I tried to export it by `export { default as Smth } from "anywhere.ts"` which did not work. It worked for me like this:

```js
import Smth from "./anywhere";

export { Smth }
```

With this my types got generated as I would like it to. I also used this `vite.config.ts`:

```js
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        dts({
            rollupTypes: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        outDir: './dist',
        lib: {
            // src/indext.ts is where we have exported the component(s)
            entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
            name: "MyModule",
            // the name of the output files when the build is run
            fileName: "my-mdule",
            formats: ['es'],
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
            // into your library
            external: ["vue"],
            output: {
                // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
                // for externalized deps
                globals: {
                    vue: "Vue",
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

If you now have everything in our build folder you were looking for and typing are still not available in your project you properly have some issues with your modules `package.json`.

Your `package.json` should look something like this:

```json
    "main": "./dist/my-module.umd.cjs",
    "module": "./dist/my-module.js",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
            "import": "./dist/my-module.js",
            "require": "./dist/my-module.umd.cjs"
        },
        "./dist/style.css": {
          "import": "./dist/style.css",
          "require": "./dist/style.css"
        }
    },
```

The property `"types` moved from root to exports and this made me search for hours.

Hope this will help in the future!